# /ref not working. Too many }'s. Figure ref\{fig:tsdiag}

Tags: cross-referencing, ref

my code is as follows

```
\begin{figure}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{tsdiagrambraytoncycle.JPG}
    \caption{T-S diagram of the Brayton Cycle}
    \label{fig:tsdiag}
\end{figure}
```

and my cross referencing is as follows;

```
Figure ref\{fig:tsdiag} depicts the T-S Diagram for the brayton cycle
```

**however this gives the too many }'s error, even though I have the correct amount of brackets.
My googling indicates that this can be cause by certain packages (like rotating etc) however I am not using those packages. Can someone please advise? listed below are my packages in use;**

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{report}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{TUOS Stephenson}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\graphicspath{{Images/}}
\usepackage[a4paper,width=150mm,top=25mm,bottom=25mm,bindingoffset=6mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\usepackage{amsmath}



\usepackage[backend=biber,style=ieee]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{library.bib}

%for chemistry
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}

\newcounter{reaction}
\newcounter{tmp}
\newenvironment{reaction}[1][\relax]{%
    \setcounter{tmp}{\value{equation}}
    \setcounter{equation}{\value{reaction}}
    \renewcommand{\theequation}{R.\thechapter.\arabic{equation}}
    \begin{equation}    \addcontentsline{rxs}{reactions}{\protect\numberline{\theequation}#1}}{%
    \end{equation}
    \setcounter{reaction}{\value{equation}}
    \setcounter{equation}{\value{tmp}}
}

\counterwithin*{reaction}{chapter}

%endchemistry

\begin{document}
```

Thanks a lot for any possible guidance.

Comment: It should be `\ref{}`.

Comment: Thank you I've been messing with it for hours down a rabbit hole.

Comment: Good. Try to learn some basic tutorial on LaTeX. Braces `{}` should occur in pairs. If you use `\{` or `\}` is to print a real brace in the text, and this one don't need to occur in pairs. In your case, you typed `\{ }`, so the right one does not mathc to the left one. Also, the command should start with backslash, so `\ref{}`.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SE. Could you please add a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that)? You only placed code snippets and a preambule that contain unrelated package.

Answer (score 2):

As commented, it should be `\ref{}`.  The `\{` escapes the `{` to type a literal `{`, and then TeX uses the `}` to pair with a previous (unescaped) `{`.  Since that unescaped `{` doesn't exist, there's too many `}`.